# How to combine several BAT scripts in one. Script must create null variables, sent it in String and start from cmd call full comand

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file, cmd, call

This is simple program on BAT for start my Java program.
I write some simple scripts for Dell Foglight (monitoring system like Zabbix or Nagios) on Java. Foglight can't start jar file, so I use a *.bat file with variables. Foglight put variables which I need in environment, and when *.bat file start up, *.bat sent from environment filled parameters to my Java program.

Simple program which I use:

```
@echo off

java -jar CheckTcp.jar %asd_0_hostname% %asd_0_port%
```

Now I have changed my file and create:

```
@echo off

java -jar CheckTcp.jar %asd_0_hostname% %asd_0_port% %asd_1_hostname% %asd_1_port% %asd_2_hostname% %asd_2_port% %asd_3_hostname% %asd_4_port% .. %asd_49_hostname% %asd_49_port%
```

I want to improve my *.bat file.
I have used parameter

```
set>setInfo.txt
```

And fount that Foglight create some variables in environment

```
 asd=asdList
 asd_0__hostname=8.8.8.8 
 asd_0_port=8080
 asd_1__hostname=10.200.10.10
 asd_1_port=8040
 asd_row=3
```

It's would be great to create variables by used `asd_row`.
Now I have 3 simple Bat programs witch I need to combine in one.

1.Program which can write all in one String variable.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET row=3
SET /a count=row
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do call set "Myvar=%%Myvar%%, %%a"
ECHO %Myvar:~2%
```

> Result: 1, 2, 3

2.Program which can start variable from `cmd`. It start my program with a lot of parameters, it can uses my new String variable.

```
set myA=java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar
set myB=%asd_0_hostname% %asd_0_port%
>"temp.cmd"  echo %myA% %myB%
call temp.cmd
```

> Result Start a program and sent variables from environment to my Java file

3.Program which can create a names of my variables

```
@echo off
set  row=3
set /a row-=1
for /l %%a in (0,1,%row%) do (
set  "asd_%%a_port: "
)
```

> Result is: asd_0_port asd_1_port asd_2_port

Comment: I'm sure there is a question in there somewhere. How many files will be produced and please provide a sample of each desired file.

Comment: I have fully changed Second program, and try to put in Variable `myB` string of  variables `asd_0_hostname asd_1_hostname asd_2_hostname` using First or Third program

Comment: In 1 file will be produced 1 filed:

Comment: `java -jar CheckTcp.jar %asd_0_hostname% %asd_0_port% %asd_1_hostname% %asd_1_port%

Answer (score 0):

I totally changed Fist and Third program

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET row=2
SET /a count=row-1
for /l %%a in (0,1,%count%) do call set "Myvar=%%Myvar%% asd_%%a_host asd_%%a_port "
ECHO %Myvar:~2%
```

> Result:    asd_0_hostname asd_0_port asd_1_hostname asd_1_port

But I can't write this in the *.txt, via command

```
>"temp.cmd"  echo %myA% %myB%
```

Why is it so?

I Want sent `%Myvar%` in my Second program instead of `%myB%`,
The code you can lock below:

```
set myA=java -jar CheckOneHostByTcpPort.jar
set myB=%asd_0_hostname% %asd_0_port%
>"temp.cmd"  echo %myA% %myB%
call temp.cmd
```

> Result Start a program and sent variables from environment to my Java file

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET row=%table_rowCount%
SET /a count=row-1
for /l %%a in (0,1,%count%) do  call set "myvar=%%myvar%% !table_%%a_hostname! !table_%%a_port! !table_%%a_warning! !table_%%a_critical! "
set myA=java -jar YourJavaProgram.jar
>"temp.cmd"  echo %myA% %myvar:~1%
call temp.cmd
```

This program not work correctly if it started with out variables,I fix this problem in my java program.